# How to force Woocommerce to deliver the product to the paypal adress which was used?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

i have a woocommerce shop where i sell keys. After the payment my customers get the key instantly.

Problem: There are many scammers who used stolen credentials. They send the keys to their own email and pay with an other paypal account.

So afterwards i have to refund the owner of the account.

Is there a possibility to link the order to the paypal adress?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't see how PayPal users getting keys to something they didn't buy solves your problem at all?

Comment: I think PayPal does give you the email address, [payer_email in the IPN buyer details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#buyer-information-variables), but the bad news is that I don't see any way for you to hook [WC_Gateway_Paypal_IPN_Handler](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.0.1/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-ipn-handler.php) to save this from the response. You may have to edit / replace that class.